# Convert batch EPS to SVG using ImageMagick?

Tags: svg, automation, eps, file-conversion, imagemagick

Is there an easy way to convert a batch of EPS files to SVG format, using ImageMagick or something else?

I have thousands of vector files in EPS format and I need to convert them to SVG.

Comment: ImageMagick isn't really meant for converting vector formats, it's possible but it will convert to an intermediary raster image which isn't good (see http://imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#vector)

Comment: Agreed.  The sort of obvious answer is the use a Photoshop action to accomplish this task.

Comment: [Converting from EPS to SVG format](http://superuser.com/questions/198460/converting-from-eps-to-svg-format) may give you what you need

Answer (score 3):

As has been said by others, ImageMagick isn't really for vector-to-vector conversion.

I don't have much experience using [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) with `.eps` files, so I don't know reliable it is for ones that weren't generated by the `barcode` command, but, at least in theory, you can do this using its command-line interface.

(It used to have a bug in its EPS parser which would mess up the colors, but that was apparently fixed in 2015.)

Given that you're interested in using ImageMagick, I'm guessing you have access to a POSIX-compliant shell, so here's how you'd do it in shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

for file in *.eps; do
    inkscape -f "$file" --export-plain-svg="${file%.*}.svg"
done
```

Some other options which I haven't used myself, but which [others swear by](https://superuser.com/q/198460/48014) include:

- [Uniconverter](https://sourceforge.net/projects/uniconvertor/)
- `ps2pdf -dEPSCrop` (from Ghostscript) followed by `pdf2svg`

Comment: Files generated by `ps2pdf -dEPSCrop myFile.eps` followed by `pdf2svg myFile.pdf myFile.svg` seem to be a bit larger than the ones generated by Inkscape. Like 788k vs 430k.

Comment: Given that Inkscape presents a dialog with a bunch of different tunables when loading an EPS file interactively, I could see that happening on the input side (interpreting EPS) or the output side (writing SVG) or both. Since pdf2svg is a frontend for Poppler, how does the Inkscape GUI's "Import via Poppler" checkbox change things? Also, how do they compare if your run both through an SVG minifier like [svgcleaner](https://github.com/RazrFalcon/svgcleaner), [svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo), or [scour](https://github.com/scour-project/scour)?

Comment: Looks like it's a bit of both. With the EPS I tried it on, pdf2svg made a 35K SVG while Inkscape made a 13K one. (and Inkscape via Poppler did 43K) SVGO dropped the pdf2svg output to 4.1K while leaving Inkscape unchanged, but it reset the font on both. SVG Cleaner got Inkscape down to 4.1K and didn't make visible changes to either, but it only got pdf2svg's output down to 20K. I'd need to hack together some custom comparison scripting to identify exactly which SVGO option is responsible and what file size SVGO can achieve from pdf2svg with it disabled but everything otherwise at defaults.

Answer (score 1):

[Scribus](https://www.scribus.net/) is an Open Source software.  Use *File/Open...* to open the EPS file and then *File/Export/As SVG...* to save the result as an SVG file. Unlike ImageMagick, it will keep the vector format.

Scribus has [scripting capabilities](https://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Command_line_scripts) and if I get [this page](https://wiki.scribus-user.de/scripter:start#liste_aller_konstanten_und_funktionen) right, the function name for exporting is `ImageExport()` but there's no example on how to use it.

Update: in Scribus 1.4.6, there's no export functionality for SVG via `ImageExport()`. I did

```
svg = scribus.ImageExport()
print(svg.allTypes)
```

which only gives me the types 'bmp', 'ico', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'ppm', 'tif', 'tiff', 'xbm' and 'xpm'.

Scribus 1.5.3 adds 'cur', 'dds', 'icns', 'pbm', 'pgm', 'wbmp and 'webp', but still has no SVG export.

I have opened a [feature request](https://bugs.scribus.net/view.php?id=15120).

Comment: This just worked well for me.  Other methods did not preserve the vector nature of the  image.

Answer (score 0):

Since I've faced this issue many times, I've ended with a service based solution.
Normally I use the service from https://cloudconvert.com/ but recently I noticed they also offers a cli which can be invoked to convert any kind of file that one can see on their site.

Just register, obtain a free (just be sure of the free limitations) API Key, install their cli as [described here](https://cloudconvert.com/cli) and then (optional) create this simple script for a drag&drop conversion:

```
'echo off
set CLOUDCONVERT_API_KEY=[your_api_key]
cloudconvert -f svg %*
```